# Android XML Layout - ImageView taking all space

Tags: android, imageview

This is my first post on Stackoverflow.
My question is related to ImageViews : I have a simple XML layout file composed of two LinearLayouts included in a general LinearLayout.
The first LinearLayout contains a simple ImageView, and the second one contains three buttons.

My problem is that the ImageView takes all the space on the screen and therefore the three buttons aren't displayed.
I've done quite a lot of research, I've tried to change everything I could to make it work and the only thing that did the trick was to turn the ImageView layout_width attribute into a dp value.
Why do I have to do that? Is it somehow related to the dimension of the original picture (1280 x 800)?

The XML file is :

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/linearMainCreateTape"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 tools:context="com.example.anthony.walkmanfreeversion.CreateTapeActivity" >
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/highresoltape1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Button1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Button2"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Button3"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post Your xml layout please

Comment: Yes Opiatefuchs I'm sorry I did something wrong and it didn't post it ! There it is now ! Thanks for your consideration :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `android:layout_weight` in order to define how much space should be taken by the layouts:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/linearMainCreateTape"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  tools:context="com.example.anthony.walkmanfreeversion.CreateTapeActivity" >
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/highresoltape1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button3"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the example above both inner layouts have the same weight, so they bot fill 50% of the height.

If all views reserve the entire available height (`match_parent`) then the first one wins. So in your case the top level layout (`linearMainCreateTape`) fills the whole height and the layout which contains the ImageView does the same. So there's nothing left for the three buttons below it.

Comment: ' android:layout_height="0dp" ' gives me an error saying that the view will be invisible

Comment: Did you add the `android:layout_weight` as well? p.s. I just fixed the `android:weight` above. Setting the height to `0dp` is the recommended value to use for views that use a weight. Check example from the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Comment: I just added the layout_weight : 1 attribute to the LinearLayout containing the ImageView and now it's working correctly ! 
Still, I don't understand why. 
Thank you for trying to help me :o)

Comment: Consider `match_parent` as greedy. If more than one view or layout are on the same level the first one fills up the parent layout completely. `wrap_content` means that views or layouts take as much room as they need to display it's content. Finally `layout_weight` allows to define a kind of importance value. These sites give more detailed explanations: http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-android-s-layout-weight-attribute.html, http://ugia.io/2012/01/19/android-linearlayout-distribution-explained-weight-and-sizes/

Answer (score 4):

For anyone having this issue, there is a quick solution for that.

In your imageView XML add the following property:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

*for. eg*

```
<ImageView
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

> If you are using a Constraint Layout, don't forget to add the constraints.